# Modifying A Previous Commit From Git Tower

Tags: git, git-tower

I have a local repository that I need to go back to and change what the commit was. The reason I need to do this is because in the commit I had added a file that was deleted to the commit and that is not what I want to do after all. I want to keep it in there with the original name.

The following explaination is working off my development branch locally for my local repository.

The initial commit was all the files in the default installation of Laravel 5.2. I have always been told to change the .env.example file to .env however what I wasn't aware of it is also a good idea to include this file like it is so that if someone were to fork it then they know what environment variables they need to include in the application.

In my second commit I had renamed the file to just .env however for the development branch I would like to keep the file in the development branch.

How can I go back to that second commit and remove the fact I had deleted that file?

Comment: you can `git commit --amend` from the command line see: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit

Comment: Will that change any other commits I did after that commit or what's in my working files that have yet to be committed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716

Comment: That's great but doesn't tell me anything about amending previous commits.

Comment: For historical purposes, `amend` is not always the best option, especially in a shared repo among other developers. I'd say if you deleted a file on accident and committed it as such. Go find your local copy of the file and add it back in and commit that

Comment: @chris, I believe he is only working on local commits that have not been pushed anywhere yet.

Comment: Its not a shared repo. Its a private repo.

Comment: I figured as much to, but for someone who stumbles across this Q&A some time in the future from now.. I felt it was important to put the disclosure there for them to see :-)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so let's say the file is called `filename` and the commit where you deleted it is `abc123`. Run the following: `git rebase -1 abc123~`. This will pop up your editor with all your commits starting with `abc123`. On the first line, change "pick" to "edit", then close your editor. Git will replay `abc123`, then stop. At that point, recover your file with `git checkout head~ -- /path/to/filename`, then amend the commit with `git commit --amend -C head`. Git will then replay the rest of your commits, and you should be fine.

Comment: OP was asking about Tower.

Answer (score 0):

To modify the most recent commit

```
git commit --amend
```

To modify previous commits, and/or more than one

```
git rebase
```

Both of these are well documented elsewhere and a quick search or `git help` will show you the documentation.

Comment: OP was asking about Tower